# Disabling desktop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

So, i have the following jquery:

```
jQuery('.button').click(function(e) {
            var isMobiles = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? true : false;                  
            if(!isMobiles) {
                jQuery('.button').featherlight(); //lightbox function   
                alert("desktop");                   
            }else{
                alert("mobile");
            }   
        })
```

In desktop view, I get an alert "Desktop" and featherlight lightbox.

In mobile view, I am still getting the featherlight lightbox and alert "mobile".

I am really confused to why the lightbox function still loads in mobile view when I get "mobile" alert?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is definetly not doing that.

Try this:

1. Write `​$._data( $('.button')[0], "events" );` on your console to see the events attached to that element.
   We take the first `.button`, because they should all have the same events attached
2. Check the response, search for any events calling `.featherlight()`

Comment: That helped me to figure out why it wasn't working. Thanks